# Print a .csv file with comma separated values in a specified order

Tags: python, loops

I have csv/txt file which has the input data like below.

```
a 123,456
b 887
c 198
d 123,456
```

I'm expecting the below output using Python:

```
a 123
a 456
b 887
c 198
d 123
d 456
```

I've tried using both csv and txt readers and couldn't get the intended results.

```
file = open("tt_xx_20191111_113854.txt","r")

for line in file:

  fields = line.split(",")

print(fields[0])
```

I just receive the last row as the output. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an indentation error in the code. The last line should be inside the loop instead of being outside. like this -

```py
file = open("tt_xx_20191111_113854.txt","r")
for line in file:
  row, fields = line.split(" ")
  for value in fields.split(","):
      print(row + " " + value)
```

Comment: Didn't receive the intended output, I'd like to see the values after comma to be displayed as mentioned above. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I have edited the code in the answer. Logic: First split using space, which gives you first row and a list of comma-separated values of second column. Then split the list on basis of comma.

Answer (score 1):

like @Anshuman wrote, you got a intention error. If you now want to print the fields of the values all seperate you need a second for in loop like so:

```py
s = io.StringIO("123,456\n887\n198\n123,456")

for line in s:
    fields = line.strip().split(",")
    for field in fields:
        print(str(field))
```

Notice that i replaced the load, because I dont have the file to check. Output is as following:

```
123
456
887
198
123
456
```